# Find the coordinates of $3x^3-2x^2+x+4$ in the base $(3,-1+x,-2+x^2,-3+x^3)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I did:

$$\alpha_1(3)+\alpha_2(-1+x)+\alpha_3(-2+x^2)+\alpha_4(-3+x^3) = \\
x^3(\alpha_4)+x^2(\alpha_3)+x(\alpha_2)+(3\alpha_1-\alpha_2-2\alpha_3-3\alpha_4)$$

$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\alpha_4 = 3 \\
\alpha_3=-2\\
\alpha_2=1 \\
3\alpha_1-\alpha_2-2\alpha_3-3\alpha_4=4
\end{array}
\right. \\
\Leftrightarrow \\
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\alpha_4 = 3 \\
\alpha_3=-2\\
\alpha_2=1 \\
\alpha_1=2
\end{array}
\right. \\$$

The coordinates are $(2,1,-2,3)$. Is this correct?

Bonus question: Determine the vector $(1,-2,3,-3)$ in the given base.

I did:
$$(1)*(3)+(-2)*(-1+x)+(3)(-2+x^2)+(-3)*(-3+x^3) = \\
3+2-2x-6+3x^2+9-3x^3=\\
8-2x+3x^2-3x^3$$

Is this correct?

Comment: The method is correct but it seems to me that $\alpha_1 = \frac{10}{3}$

Comment: Doesn't $3a_1-a_2-2a_3-3a_4=0$ when $a_1=2, a_2=1, a_3=-2, a_4=3$?

Comment: check:  $\dfrac{10}3(3)+1(-1+x)+-2(-2+x^2)+3(-3+x^3)=4+x-2x^2+3x^3$

Comment: Looks like you did the both parts right, barring a careless mistake.

Comment: Actually, I wonder if on the bonus they want you to express that vector in terms of the given basis.  I suspect so.

Comment: @ChrisCuster That was the idea... isn't this how you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you did the first part right, barring a careless mistake.

For the second part, $x^3-2x^2+3x-3=3a+(-1+x)b+(-2+x^2)c+(-3+x^3)d$.  So solve as above.

$d=1, c=-2, b=3$ and $a=-1/3$.

So $(-1/3, 3, -2, 1)$.

This problem can also be done by inverting the change of basis matrix: $\begin{pmatrix}3&-1&-2&-3\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$, and multiplying by $(1,-2,3,-3)^t$.

Comment: In what basis is that vector $(1,-2,3,-3)$ supposed to be given? From your answer, it seems that you assume the basis is standard for polynomials i.e. $(x^3, x^2,x,1)$. But how can we decide that it wasn't supposed to be $(1,x,x^2,x^3)$?

Comment: Good catch @Don.  I found the problem a little ambiguous.  Not sure who/what the source is.  But they could have spelled it out more.

Comment: It's from an exam from a previous year (source is my professor). This is all the question says. I think the given base is supposed to be the one in the title.

Comment: Yes.  I think it's correct.